# How can I get around "mixed active content" highcharts exporting error?

Tags: highcharts, export, highmaps, mixed-content

It appears you cannot use Exporting with https, because of "mixed active content" error.

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://export.highcharts.com/"
```

You can see this problem by viewing one of the Highmaps demos:

This (http) works:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/distribution/

This (https) doesn't:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/distribution/

Is there any way to allow Exporting to work with an https page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exporting URL defaults to `'http://export.highcharts.com'`. You can manually set it to use https for the same address.

In code ([updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48p2e64m/)):

```
exporting: {
    url: 'https://export.highcharts.com'
}
```

Comment: From version 4.2.6 the default is `https` instead of `http`.