# Calling Highcharts export to jpeg but the source is https and exporting is http (security warnings issued by browser)

Tags: highcharts, https

The issue that I am having is that my source website where Highcharts is deployed is on https. However when you call the exporting function (to download the graph as an image) a security warning is issued by the browser. That is the browser is going from https to http for the export and is warning of security issue.

Does Highcharts have a means to export call through Https?

Much appreciated.

Comment: How are you referencing HighCharts? The *default* CDN is `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js`, which is already HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found in:
[How can I get around "mixed active content" highcharts exporting error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538500/how-can-i-get-around-mixed-active-content-highcharts-exporting-error)

```
exporting: {
    url: 'https://export.highcharts.com'
}
```

Thanks.